# Why is SetObjectField so slow?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

So I was benchmarking JNI functions on my tablet (averaged over 3x5000 calls), each call took:

```
SetObjectField        0.35 milliseconds
NewStringUTF          0.03 milliseconds
GetObjectField        0.003 milliseconds
SetBooleanField       0.002 milliseconds 
SetObjectArrayElement 0.002 milliseconds
```

So SetBooleanField, SetObjectArrayElement and GetObjectField are reasonable fast; NewStringUTF has to be slow, since it is allocating new memory; but what can SetObjectField possible do that  takes so long? Is it not just writing a pointer at a known location? Is it slow everywhere, or only on my old Android 4.4 tablet? CheckJNI is enabled ("Late-enabling CheckJNI"), does that change things?

benchmark code in Pascal:

```
for i := 1 to 3 do begin
  starttime := now;
  for k := 1 to 5000 do  
    env^^.SetObjectField(env, jbook, bookFields.accountL, jacc);
  log('TESTING TIME: ' + inttostr(round( (now - starttime)*MSecsPerDay)));
end;
```

or

```
javaarray := env^^.NewObjectArray(env, 5001, bookClass, nil); 
for i := 1 to 3 do begin
  starttime := now;
  for k := 1 to 5000 do  
    env^^.SetObjectArrayElement(env, javaarray, k, jbook);
  log('TESTING TIME: ' + inttostr(round( (now - starttime)*MSecsPerDay)));
end;
```

`jbook`, `jacc`, `bookClass`, `bookFields.accountL` are initialized with objects/class/field from my app. And they are not `nil`/null (with nil SetObjectField is fast).  I do the averaging manually.

Comment: Show us your benchmark code.  I suspect that the real cause of these results is a problem with your benchmark.

Comment: @StephenC added the relevant loop

Comment: Sorry, but we need to see the complete benchmark.  The actual code of the benchmark that gives the results in your question.

Comment: Well, I put that above for loop in my app and then changed the inner k loop. There are [3000 lines](https://github.com/benibela/videlibri/blob/3e21465a15aaf4a2b8c6dad788e69b69ab6b0d19/android/androidutils.pas#L1126) concerning JNI and it gave [this output](https://gist.github.com/benibela/fe74cc0370bf00b1c47c6e23696f69bf#file-gistfile1-txt-L32-L42)

Comment: What you have shown me does not convince me that your benchmarking is sound.  I cannot see anything to say how you deal with JVM warmup effects.  Without this, we *could* just be chasing a mirage ... an artifact of the way you are benchmarking.  Also, I don't think anyone else could reliably reproduce your results, since your technique seems to be to change the code and rerun it.  Someone else may be prepared to work with / from this ...